# css: как лучше реализовать таблицу элементов (без использования display: grid)

Tags: css, html, flexbox, position

Подскажите, как лучше реализовать расположение 3х элементов

```
<div class = 'left'></div>
<div class = 'top'></div>
<div class = 'bottom'></div>
```

так, чтобы элемент `left` был слева от двух других элементов `top` и `bottom`, по высоте был равен сумме `top` и `bottom` (см. рисунок)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я реализовал через позиционирование, но результат был не совсем тот (см. рисунок)

```
.left {
    position:                   absolute;

    width:                      250px;
    height:                     100%;
}

.top {
    position:                   absolute;

    left:                       250px;

    width:                      calc(100% - 250px);
    max-width:                  calc(320px * 4);
    height:                     50px;       
}

.bottom {   
    position:                   relative;
    left:                       250px;
    top:                        50px;

    width:                      calc(100% - 250px);
    max-width:                  calc(320px * 4);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли реализовать это через flex?
Не хочется использовать `display: grid`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если подходит вариант с дополнительными блоками, то можно сделать так:

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.inner-wrap {
  width: 100%;
}

.left {
  width: 250px;
  background: red;
}

.top {
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}

.bottom {
  height: 250px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class='left'></div>
  <div class="inner-wrap">
    <div class='top'></div>
    <div class='bottom'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: хотелось бы как раз без дополнительных блоков - только 1 наружный и 3 внутренних

Comment: Можно комбинировать с абсолютным позиционированием: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ELmvvY?editors=1100

Answer (score 1):

Если продолжить Вашу идею с `position: absolute;`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}


.wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 250px;
}

.left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
  
    background: orangered;
}

.top {
    max-width: calc(320px * 4);
    height: 50px;       
  
    background: lime;
}

.bottom {  
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    max-width: calc(320px * 4);
  
    background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class = 'left'></div>
  <div class = 'top'></div>
  <div class = 'bottom'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: вся старая гвардия в сборе, то есть в ответах (+)

Answer (score 1):

Такую раскладку легко можно реализовать на флексбоксе, без магических чисел в значении высоты блоков, вычислений, абсолютного позиционирования и т. п., где каждый блок будет подстраиваться под нужную высоту контента. Обратите внимание на строчку `flex-grow: 1` — благодаря этому свойству блок начинает занимать все свободное пространство по высоте.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

main, .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

main {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
  flex-direction: column;
}

header, section, aside {
  padding: 1em;
}

aside {
  background-color: #666;
}

header {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

section {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <aside>sidebar</aside>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>header</header>
    <section>content</section>
  </div>
</main>
```